# How to get access to Google Cloud Save APIs in android studio?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am trying to use Google Cloud Save to store data on cloud for my android app. I have seen every possible tutorial but I can't get access to Google Cloud Save APIs in my Android Studio(Beta) 0.9.1. I tried to try trial version of Cloud Save at Developer's site  [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcs/index.html) . They ask me to sign up for free trial but they always shows me a page in the end which says "Thank you for signing up! Trusted tester program is now closed but we'll notify you when Google Cloud Save is available." ..  How do I get get access to Google Cloud Save APIs in my Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Google Cloud Save** is currently in private beta, and we're gathering feedback from our trial partners as was announced at I/O -- Please see for additional information:  http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/06/reimagining-developer-productivity-and-data-analytics-in-the-cloud-news-from-google-io.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you tell me that how can I be a trial partner??

Comment: Any word on when this will become available for public usage? We've been waiting for a while now...

Comment: If you're looking for similar functionality that is available now you can give Firebase a shot - it is now part of the Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Cloud Save seems simpler and - for those using google datastore - much better then Firebase.  I hope that Google's purchase of Firebase doesn't kill their plans for Cloud Save.